# When is $\int^1_0 f=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int^1_{\epsilon} f$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a measurable function defined on $[0,1]$.
>
> (a) Suppose $f$ is nonnegative, show that
> $$\int_0^1 f=\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_\epsilon^1 f .
> $$
> (b) Does the conclusion in part (a) still hold if the assumption that $f \geq 0$ is replaced by the assumption that $f$ is bounded?
>
> (c) Does the conclusion in part (a) still hold if the assumption that $f \geq 0$ is replaced by the assumption that
> $$
> \lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^1 f
> $$
> exists and is finite?

I want to know how to prove (a). I used $f_n=f\chi_{[\frac{1}{n}, 1]}$ and LMCT for part (a) and LBCT for part (b). But I cannot determine whether (c) is correct.

Comment: But there is no such thing called $f_n$ here in this question, and how should I notate $f$ if such $f_n$ is defined as yours?

Answer (score 1):

(c) is essentially the statement "Every convergent series is absolutely convergent."  As hopefully we all learned in our intro calculus classes, this is false.  For instance, if $a_n = (-1)^n/n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges.

To see how this connects to (c), fix any $a_n$ so that the series converges conditionally.  We need to turn the series into a integral, so we define $g(x) = a_{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ for $x\in [1,\infty)$.  The fact that the series converges conditionally becomes, in terms of $g$, the fact that $g$ is improperly Riemann integrable, but not Lebesgue integrable, on $[1,\infty)$.  (as mentioned in my hint in the comment, we could also use any such function in place of our $g$ here, so if you wanted it to be continuous, you can use $x \mapsto \sin(x)/x$ instead)

To change the domain from $[1,\infty)$ to $(0,1]$, we apply the substitution $u = 1/x$, giving us the fact that $f(x) = x^{-2}g(x^{-1})$ is improperly Riemann integrable, but not Lebesgue integrable, on $(0,1]$.

Therefore, under the assumptions of (c), we cannot conclude $\int_0^1 f = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_\varepsilon^1 f.$